# Finding the count of negative sub-arrays for a given array

Tags: java, algorithm, array, complexity

I want to improve my implementation for the following problem:

> You are given an array of `n` integers. A sub-array is "*Negative*" if sum of all the integers in that sub-array is negative. Count the number of "*Negative sub-arrays*" in the input array.
>
> *Note:* Subarrays are contiguous chunks of the main array. For example if the array is `{1,2,3,5}` then some of the subarrays are `{1}, {1,2,3}, {2,3,5}, {1,2,3,5}` etc. But `{1,2,5}` is not an subarray as it is not contiguous.
>
> #### Input Format:
>
> The first line consists an integer `n`. The next line will contain `n` space seperated integers. Value of `n` will be at most \$100\$. The numbers in the array will range between \$-10000\$ to \$10000\$.
>
> #### Output Format:
>
> Print the answer to the problem.

I am using two loops. It's clearing the test cases, but can I do it with only one loop?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

   public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        byte T = Byte.parseByte(br.readLine());
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        int[] arr = new int[T];
        for(int i = 0; i < T; i++){
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }
        int sum = 0, count = 0;;
        for(int i = 0; i < T; i++){
             sum = 0;
             sum += arr[i];// If the number itself is negative count++
              if(sum < 0){
                    count++;
                }
            for(int j = i + 1; j < T; j++){
                sum += arr[j];
                if(sum < 0){// If the most recent sum is -ve, count++
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jamal how to get this yellow background effect in the editor, by the way thanks for the work. It certainly looks better.

Comment: It's a blockquote, which is applied with the quotes button in the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Simplifications

If you look at your main loop:

> ```
>     int sum = 0, count = 0;;
>     for(int i = 0; i < T; i++){
>          sum = 0;
>          sum += arr[i];// If the number itself is negative count++
>           if(sum < 0){
>                 count++;
>             }
>         for(int j = i + 1; j < T; j++){
>             sum += arr[j];
>             if(sum < 0){// If the most recent sum is -ve, count++
>                 count++;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

you can see that there are two blocks of code that do the same thing.  You can remove one block by noticing that starting the `j` loop at `i` instead of `i+1` will do the initial check of the number itself.  Another thing you could do is move the `int sum` declaration inside the for loop.  So the final result would look like this:

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < T; j++) {
            sum += arr[j];
            if (sum < 0) {// If the most recent sum is -ve, count++
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

## Complexity

As far as your complexity question, I don't believe that you can solve this problem with better than an \$O(n^2)\$ solution, so your two loops seem fine.

Comment: Thanks for the review. Thanks indeed. I don't feel mature enough to pass judgement on your answer, but I gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3):

It can actually be **solved in O(n*logn)** using the fact that the total number of negative subarrays will be equal to the number of inversions in the partial sum array accumulator (where accumulator[i] = sum of all elements in arr from 0 to i), plus the number of negative elements in accumulator. We can use a **merge-sort variant** to obtain this quantity in a divide and conquer fashion. Feel free to ask questions about this approach, it's my first Stack Exchange post!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static int merge(int[] arr, int left1, int right1, int left2, int right2) {
        int[] temp = new int[right2 - left1 + 1];
        int index1 = left1;
        int index2 = left2;
        int temp_index = 0;
        int inversion_count = 0;
        while(index1 <= right1 && index2 <= right2) {
            if(arr[index1] <= arr[index2]) {
                temp[temp_index] = arr[index1];
                index1++;
                temp_index++;
            }
            else {
                //In this case we add to our inversion count:
                inversion_count += right1 - index1 + 1;
                temp[temp_index] = arr[index2];
                index2++;
                temp_index++;
            }
        }

        while(index1 <= right1) {
            temp[temp_index] = arr[index1];
            index1++;
            temp_index++;
        }

        while(index2 <= right2) {
            temp[temp_index] = arr[index2];
            index2++;
            temp_index++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            arr[left1 + i] = temp[i];
        }

        return inversion_count;
    }

    public static int findNegativeSubarrays(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
        if(right < left) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(right == left) {
            if(arr[left] < 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                return 0;    
            }
        }

        int mid = (left + right)/2;
        int num1 = findNegativeSubarrays(arr, left, mid);
        int num2 = findNegativeSubarrays(arr, mid+1, right); 
        int num3 = merge(arr, left, mid, mid+1, right);

        return num1 + num2 + num3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        int accumulator[] = new int[n];
        accumulator[0] = arr[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            accumulator[i] = accumulator[i-1] + arr[i];
        }

        System.out.println(findNegativeSubarrays(accumulator, 0, n-1));
    }
}
```